# Collapse section(s) in UICollectionView List

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell, ios14

I have this `UICollectionView` List:
[image]

And I want the sections to be collapse able, just like this example image:
[image: image2]

How can I achieve that?
Also, this is my code of the `UICollectionView` configurations (in viewDidLoad()):

```
let config = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .grouped)
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout =
      UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: config)
```

I'm using iOS 14 beta 6, and Xcode version 12 (beta 6)
Thanks

Comment: i would encourage you to use tableview for this, it will be much more easy

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I won't use Table View because the collapse sections feature is available only for uicollectionview (new in iOS 14), and I also need to use it for grid layouts, and as far as I know, there are no table view grid layout because table view is built for rows.

Comment: yes if you want a grid layout as well then collectionview is the right option